# Google Script UrlFetchApp “method” : “delete” not working

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, http-status-code-404, urlfetch

I have not used the Delete method in API before, but I tried it out several times and it doesn't affect the deletion on the system via API.

Please note that there is no error thrown while doing this

I am not sure how to go about it, cause I have tried different variations of the code and still not getting the data deleted from the system. If anyone has an idea of how to use this method, kindly help.

Here is my code.

```
    for (var i = 0; i<range.length; i++) {
        if(range[i][0] == searchString) {
        var lastRow = sheet.getRange(2+i,1,1,11).getValues();
        //var user_id = sheet.getRange("I2:I" + sheet.getLastRow()).getValues();
        var data ={
        'hours_per_day':lastRow[0][6],
        'starts_at':lastRow[0][7],
         'ends_at': lastRow[0][7],
         'user_id': lastRow[0][8],
         'assignable_id':lastRow[0][9],

     }

            var delete_options = {
            'method': 'DELETE',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',

          };
var url = 'https://api.10000ft.com/api/v1/users/'+data.user_id+'/assignments/assignable_id='+ data.assignable_id+'&auth='+AUTH;
          var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, delete_options);
         if (response.getResponseCode() === 200) {
          var json = JSON.parse(response);         
          sheet.getRange(2+i, 11).setValue('Pass'); 
          }
        else {
        sheet.getRange(2+i, 11).setValue('Fail');

        Logger.log(data)

        }
     }
    }
    }
```

Comment: @TheMaster, I have edited my question to reflect exactly what happens.

Comment: Does that mean post or other methods work fine without any othermodifications to the code?

Comment: @TheMaster, yes POST and GET works fine. I have tried this also on postman and works okay.

Comment: Hello @Just, what response code are you getting if you do `Logger.log(response.getResponseCode());`? Cheers!

Comment: @ale13 I am getting this code: Exception: Request failed for https://api.10000ft.com returned code 404 at canceledLeave(canceled:31:34)  . 
      **canceledLeave** is the name of the script

Comment: @Just, does the **user** with the specific **assignment** exist? Moreover, what are you getting if you change `Content-Type` to `contentType` instead? Cheers!

Comment: @ale13 the user exists. I have tried using contentType as well but still getting the same error. The line 31 that it keeps indicating has an error is **var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, delete_options);**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this modification?

#### From:

```
var delete_options = {
'method': 'DELETE',
'Content-Type': 'application/json',
};
var url = 'https://api.10000ft.com/api/v1/users/'+data.user_id+'/assignments/assignable_id='+ data.assignable_id+'&auth='+AUTH;
var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, delete_options);
```

#### To:

```
var delete_options = {method: 'DELETE'};
var url = 'https://api.10000ft.com/api/v1/users/'+data.user_id+'/assignments/'+ data.assignable_id + '?auth='+AUTH;
var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, delete_options);
```

or

```
var delete_options = {method: 'DELETE'};
var url = 'https://api.10000ft.com/api/v1/users/'+data.user_id+'/assignments/' + data.assignable_id + '?auth='+encodeURIComponent(AUTH);
var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, delete_options);
```

#### Note:

- When sample curl command of `curl -XDELETE 'https://vnext.10000ft.com/api/v1/users/<user_id>/assignments/<assignment_id>?auth=...'` is converted to Google Apps Script, it becomes above modification.
- In your script, `assignments/assignable_id='+ data.assignable_id+'&auth='+AUTH` is used. But at the official document, `assignments/<assignment_id>?auth=...` is used. So I modified like above. But from your replying comment, I confirmed `I have tried this also on postman and works okay.`. So if above modification didn't resolve the issue, please test to modify from `assignments/<assignment_id>?auth=...` to `assignments/assignable_id='+ data.assignable_id+'&auth='+AUTH`.

#### Reference:

- [Remove an Assignment for a User](https://github.com/10Kft/10kft-api/blob/7daef04619f43afcd49a98bc5e1e93059d5ce87c/sections/assignments.md#remove-an-assignment-for-a-user)

If this didn't resolve your issue, I apologize.

Comment: Thanks for this and taking the time to look at the documentation. Actually both of your solutions work. Many thanks

Comment: @Just Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved.

Answer (score 2):

The `delete_options` parameters of your request might not be the expected ones.

Also, according to the [10,000 ft API documentation](https://github.com/10Kft/10kft-api/blob/7daef04619f43afcd49a98bc5e1e93059d5ce87c/sections/assignments.md), the `DELETE` request looks like this:

```
DELETE /api/v1/users/<user_id>/assignments/<assignment_id>
```

Therefore, if you have a token required for your desired operation, you could include it in your options, something similar to this:

```
var delete_options = {
        'method': 'delete',
        'contentType': 'application/json',
        'muteHttpExceptions': true,
        'headers': {
           'Authorization' : 'bearer'+TOKEN;
           'Accept' : 'application/json'
        }
};
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to look at the code and the documentation. I have implemented your idea but still unable to delete it from the system. When I use  Logger.log(response.getResponseCode()); to see the log. This is what I get : [20-02-24 18:23:56:143 GMT 404.0

Comment: Hello @Just, does this `curl` command work? `curl -XDELETE 'https://vnext.10000ft.com/api/v1/users/<user_id>/assignments/<assignment_id>?auth=...'`? Cheers!